# Scrolling DataGridView seems to bring down performance drastically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm writing an application in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. The application communicates with several Arduino boards. Sending and receiving works asynchronously using the TAP model, and works fine.

The application is based on a Windows Form App, using .NET Framework 4.7.2. I added a DataGridView to the form, using a DataTable as DataSource. The intention is to use this DataGridView as a data logger, showing 5 columns: TimeStamp, DeviceID, Direction, Command and ErrorStatus.

If I disable the DataGridView, I reach up to 500 commands per second on a Chinese Arduino clone. On a real Arduino I seem only to get up to 244 commands per second - see other question on stackoverflow below - but this is not the question now:

[Communication speed over USB (PC/Arduino) using SerialPort in C# seems to “clip”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415004/communication-speed-over-usb-pc-arduino-using-serialport-in-c-sharp-seems-to)

When I enable my DataGridView, I see communication speed dropping to about 25 commands/second, and this is purely because of the updating of the lines in the DataGridView. But that seems only the case when the DataGridView starts scrolling.

See below code snippet:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new string[] 
{
    DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"),
    device._FMGSDevice,
    action,
    notifyData.Command,
    notifyData.notifyError.ToString()
});
if (dt.Rows.Count > maxLines)
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

dt is the DataTable that is used as DataSource for the DataGridView. For every communication, a line is added at the end of the DataTable, which then automatically updates in the DataGridView.

maxLines is a constant currently set at 500. To avoid that my DataGridView gets too much lines, I limit it to 500 lines. If the limit is reached, I remove the first line with "RemoveAt(0)" after having added the new line, to keep it at maximum 500 lines.

I now see that once the DataGridView starts **scrolling** (the "RemoveAt(0)" causes all the lines to move up with one line), the speed goes dramatically down.

**Does anyone has an idea how to speed up the scrolling?** Or is there another item I could use to log? (although, I need filtering as well).

Comment: DGV wouldn't have been my first choice for implementing this logging. Are you sending the commands on the window thread?

Comment: maybe you will have to have a list/table to keep the data, but only shows 20 or 30 rows in grid. when scrolls, then update the grid.

Comment: Try [DataGridView.VirtualMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=net-5.0#:~:text=Virtual%20mode%20is%20designed%20for,event%20to%20populate%20the%20cells.) and [Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Try to DoubleBuffer the DGV!

Comment: @CaiusJard No, the communications uses Asynchronous Task based implementation.

Comment: As mentioned, use the DGV's Virtual Mode and do not let the control auto-size the Columns based on the content (this kills the *performance*): use Columns with fixed width and  `FillWeight = 1`. As an alternative, use a ListView in Virtual Mode (an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719931/7444103)) instead of a DGV: a LV in Virtual Mode is faster than a DGV.

Comment: @TaW Using DoubleBuffer gave me a performance increase of almost 500% (5 x). Instead of 24 commands/second, I have now 118 commands/second.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly your application but you can try the delete method instead of RemoveAt and see if the performances improve. it should be:

```
DataRow dr = dtName.Rows[0];
dr.Delete();
dtName.AcceptChanges();
```

Alternatively you can increase the number of record to remove, for example remove the first 10 or 20 records instead only the first.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. Using Delete() and AcceptChanges instead of RemoveAt() seems not to bring any performance gain. I also tried with 10 and 20 rows at a time using both methods, and also this didn't give me any change. Thanks for the feedback anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @TaW worked best so far. At least, it was the easiest to implement. I have not yet experimented with Virtual Mode nor have I tried ListView, because these require quite some time to implement.

I created a derived class from DataGridView as below (see link where I found this):

[Horrible redraw performance of the DataGridView on one of my two screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)

```
class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public CustomDataGridView()
    {
        // if not remote desktop session then enable double-buffering optimization
        if (!System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
            DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Because I'm using Designer, I manually changed the code there to use the CustomDataGridView class instead.

```
this.dgLogView = new HW_Hub.CustomDataGridView();
```

Although, what I'm not sure, **is it allowed to change code in "...designer.cs"**? I have the feeling that Visual Studio "owns" this file, and make changes automatically. Do I need another way to overrule the standard implementation?

Comment: _"...designer.cs"? I have the feeling that Visual Studio "owns" this file_ Of sorts; there is a section that is reserved but the rest is fine zo change, as long as you don't botch thr syntax. The reseved area is marked as such.

Comment: Visual Studio serializes what you have added to the Form's designer. If the `CustomDataGridView` custom control is accessible (the serializer can find it), the changes you have made in the `Designer.cs` file will persist and the Control in the visual designer is replaced. BTW, this way of replacing a Control with another is quite common. The warning is related to code added to the `designer.cs` which is not subject to serialization: of course that code won't persist, so all changes will be lost when the serializer kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not to update the data automatically. People will be reading the data, maybe selecting parts of it. It is fairly annoying if the data that you just selected scrolls away.

It is similar to editing a document will parts that you are reading, or just selected suddenly disappear.

Add a "Refresh" button, which will refresh the data.

If you think that live updates of the data is important, so operators can see which data changes, consider to use a timer. If the timer elapses, refresh the data.

Something like this:

```
// the data in one Row:
class ArduinoLogData
{
    ... // properties that will be shown in the columns
}

BindingList<ArduinoLogData> DisplayedArduinoData
{
    get => (BindingList<LoggedArduinoRow>)this.DataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.DataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

// Fetch ArduinoData
IEnumerable<ArduinoLogData> FetchArduinoLogdata()
{
    ...
}
```

Consider to create an overload in which you state which arduinos must be fetched, so you can update only the arduinos that are currently visible. Use DataGridViewRow.Displayed to get the ArduinoLogData that is currently displayed:

```
IEnumerable<ArduinoLogData> DisplayedData => this.DataGridView1.Rows
    .Where(row => row.Displayed)
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<ArduinoLogData>();
```

And a method:

```
void RefreshArduinoLogData(ICollection<ArduinoLogData> itemsToRefresh)
{
    ... // update only these items.
}

void RefreshDisplayedArduinoLogData()
{
    this.RefreshArduinoLogData(this.DisplayedData.ToList());
}
```

This will update only the visible items, about 40 rows or so.

Do this once a second:

```
Timer refreshTime = new Timer
{
    AutoReset = true,
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds,
};
timer.Elapsed += OnTimerTick;
timer.Enabled = true;

void OnTimerTick(object sender, ...)
{
    this.RefreshDisplayedArduinoLogData();
}
```

Don't forget to Dispose your Timer when your Form closes, or at last when the Form is disposed.